# Android - Setting Text Message Sound Does Not Change Sound?

Tags: android, audio, sms, ringtone

My issue is that the code is not changing my Alarm tone, or the tone for when I get a text message.

The following works:

```
       private void setRingTone(int RawId, String HumanName, String fileName)
   {

       Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() +"/raw/" + fileName);

       RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
               getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
               path);  
       Log .i("TESTT", "Ringtone Set to Resource: "+ path.toString());

       RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), path)
               .play();

   }
```

However these 2 do not:

1. private void setTextTone(int RawId, String HumanName, String fileName)
      {

   ```
      Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() +"/raw/" + fileName);

      RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
              getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
              path);  
      Log .i("TESTT", "Ringtone Set to Resource: "+ path.toString());

      RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), path)
              .play();
   ```

   }

Does anyone know why the Notification does not change the sound of SMS messages, but Ringtone works. It is basically the same code??

```
EDIT I found something on Stack Overflow here (But I do Not understand it can someone clarify?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545906/how-do-i-change-the-android-sms-tone-despite-of-current-sms-tone-setting
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution is to copy the sound from the raw folder into the sdcard and from there do the following:

```
  File k = new File(path, filename);

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
  values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "TwiAppclip");
  values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "cssounds ");
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
  values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

  Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
       .getAbsolutePath());
   //do a delete here before inserting
  Uri newUri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);

  RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(),
      RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
```